# Is the set $S$ of vectors linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

$S = \{ u, v, w \}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, where  it is known that there is an invertible $3 \times 3$ matrix $D$ such that $uD = (1,2,3)$, $vD = (4,5,6)$, and $w D = (5,7,9)$.

Is the set $S$ of vectors linearly independent?

Below is what I did:

$wD = (5,7,9) = (1,2,3) + (4,5,6) = uD + vD$
Since $wB$ is a redundant vector, $w$ is a redundant vector as well. Therefore, set of vectors that contain $w$ is linearly dependent.

Is there anything wrong with my explanation ?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit your question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Write down the definition of linear independence for $S$. What does multiplication with $D$ do to it?

Comment: $(1,2,3)+(4,5,6)=(5,7,9)$ $ \Rightarrow$ ....

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have made the necessary changes, hope things are much clearer now.

Comment: You’ve shown that the set $\{uD,vD,wD\}$ is linearly dependent, but how do you conclude from this that $\{u,v,w\}$ is, too?

Comment: @amd I am thinking of treating the matrix D as a form of scalar constant. In that case, ${uD, vD, wD}$ would just be the linear combination of ${u, v, w}$.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve shown that the set $\{uD,vD,wD\}$ is linearly dependent, but have failed to justify why this implies that $\{u,v,w\}$ is also linearly dependent. As a counterexample, suppose that $u$, $v$ and $w$ are the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^3$ and $$D=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\5&7&9\end{bmatrix}.$$ Then $uD=(1,2,3)$, $vD=(4,5,6)$ and $wD=(5,7,9)$, but $u$, $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent.

The key is that $D$ is invertible. You can therefore say that $$0=0D^{-1}=(uD+vD-wD)D^{-1}=uDD^{-1}+vDD^{-1}-wDD^{-1}=u+v-w.$$

Answer (score 0):

A nonsingular $n×n$ matrix is a change of basis matrix (from the basis consisting of the columns to the standard basis).  Hence it always takes a basis to a basis.   Since this did not happen when applied to $\{u,v,w\}$ (as you have shown), it isn't a basis...